# Plot multiple csv files as subplots in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 8 csv files and I want to plot each of them as a subplot in Python matplotlib. Currently, my code plots only one csv file and I don't know how to apply it for rest of the images. Here's my code:

```
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    reader1 = 
    csv.reader(open('Sensor1_WalkingDiagonally_BigArea_Bo1.csv'), delimiter=',')

    y = list(reader1)

    del y[0]

    for row in y:
        del row[0]  # 0 for column 1, 1 for column 2, etc.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    pixels = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)

    #Plot
    plt.imshow(pixels, interpolation='none', cmap = 'viridis')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```